# Photoshop Image from html to layer(Photoshop extension)

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script, adobe-extension

I want to create a layer and at the same time put an image from html to it.
So far I did something like this:

```
var doc=document.getElementByID("img1");  //img1 is from html,it is an img tag
var newLayerRef = app.activeDocument.artLayers.add(doc);
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: I need more information about the HTML please

Comment: <img class="sketch" id="img1" src="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/original_254219_ZNuq71NSRjMWW_LJ3x9L3tnAS.jpg" alt="car" height="100" width="150">

I suppose this is the part that you need.A simple img tag